# What hosting provider allows large anon FTP uploads?

Tags: hosting, ftp, upload

I'm working on a website which allows users from different part of world to upload files upto 500 MB.

The problems are:

- As it is a HTTP transfer, it is slow.
- As it is a HTTP transfer, it is non-resumable. Users really suffer because of these two problems.

So, I want to find a FTP provider which can provide me the services meeting the following criteria:

1. To upload files with size upto 500 MB.
2. Anonymous upload.
3. If possible, in-browser solution i.e. using embed code.
4. It should be fast, may be, using distributed networks.

Please if any of you guys have came across a situation like this or similar to this share the proivder name with their websites.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are easy - almost any hosting company (godaddy etc.) will happily sell you as much storage as you like and let you FTP files up and down to it, you'll also be able to manage the user accounts and priviledges.

3 - well some have this built into their own UI but I suspect you want to embed something into your own code, in which case there are lots of chunks of GUI FTP code you can steal based on your dev environment. Alternatively there's loads of OS-specific GUI FTP clients about if a CLI scares you or your clients.

4 - FTP is a point-to-point protocol, it isn't a P2P number like bittorrent, so it'll be as fast as the slowest link between you/you-clients and the hosting company - almost certainly the pinch-point won't be at their end.